# How do I start the commandline in OrchardCMS Core

Tags: orchardcms

I created a site on [dotnest](https://stagingstoneviewnaturecenterassociates.dotnest.com/). I want to [create a custom theme](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme/). The documentation tells me to start the command line interface.

Okay, I get the latest from GitHub and [follow the instructions](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore). `dotnet run` works! Great!

Since I need orchard.exe to create a theme, [I change into the correct directory and try to run](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface/). Even after building, there is no `bin\Orchard.exe` in the dotnet core version. I check the source code and all of the Program.cs files start web servers.

How do I run the orchard command line so that I create a theme so that I can install it on dotnest?

Comment: As far as i know dotnest uses orchard 1, not orchard core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hazza mentioned in his comment, DotNest runs on Orchard 1, so you will need to download Orchard 1 from GitHub (https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/releases/tag/1.10.2) and use its Orchard.exe program to generate a theme project.

DotNest provides further instructions here to create a custom theme for DotNest: https://dotnest.com/knowledge-base/topics/theming/